# Launch a WSL script through Windows Terminal: node: command not found

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node.js

I am trying to run a node.js script in WSL from WT using the syntax `wsl.exe <command>`.

However I can't get it to find Node when launched this way and get the following :

```
PS C:\> wsl.exe -- node -v
/bin/bash: node: command not found
```

In WSL, node is installed and works as expected :

```
/mnt/c$ node -v
v14.13.0
```

In a bash script just in case :

```
// test.sh
#!/bin/bash
node -v

/mnt/c$ ./test.sh
v14.13.0

PS C:\> wsl.exe -- ./test.sh
/mnt/c/test.sh: line 2: node: command not found
```

What am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? I think I have a similar problem where I have a executable script in my path but trying to run it with wsl doesn't work. I have to be inside the shell.

Comment: Did you figure this out. I’ve been spending all day I can’t understand why it’s doing this. Defualt is set and I’ve not like nvm installed. But when I run wsl nvm … says it’s not installed ???? What the frig??

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the full path to node - there is most likely no paths defined